# Launching C# WPF from Java causes FileNotFoundExceptions

Tags: c#, java, wpf, java-native-interface, c++-cli

I have a existing Java Project which needs functionality from a SDK written in C#. It should open a WPF Window and send the information back to Java on close.

For a basic connection of those two worlds i created a Java Project ("DotNetCaller") calling native functions. These are implemented in a C++/CLI Project ("DotNetBridge") which calls the C# Project ("DotNetApplication").

I already can set Strings from Java in C# and callback from C# to Java.

But as soon as i add a WPF Window and try to launch it with:

```
 Application app = new Application();
 app.Run(new DotNetWindow());
```

in a STA Thread it crashes.

The DotNetApplication doesnt find mscorlib.resources, after i provide the DLL, PresentationFramework.resources is missing and if i provide that, the DotNetApplication.resource is missing (which i cant provide).

If i call the DotNetApplication alone or from the DotNetBridge the Window displays as expected.

Can anyone tell ma what i'm really missing here?

Thanks

**Edit:**

I looked at [this example](http://codefry.blogspot.co.at/2012/01/calling-net-dlls-from-java-code-without.html) once more and tried to adapt it to my needs.
I have set the dll directory of the ResolveEventHandler to the .NET dir in "Referenced Assemblies"

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0

and added a Window in C#.

It failed aswell but with a new exception in the C++ part rather than C#.
The ResolveHandler gets called with an empty argument causing an uncatchable exception in mscorelib.
I added a check if the String is empty and this basic approach works fine now.

I'm still unsure if i have the correct approach for this, so feel free to contribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your [`AppDomain::AssemblyResolve`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve.aspx) handler probably needs to be overhauled and based on your own understanding of what you want to do. There is some guidance [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff527268.aspx). The basic rule is that you return `nullptr` for requests that you can't handle.

But first you have to plan the locations in which you want to deploy (and/or debug) your assemblies. A simple layout would be to put all of the assemblies that your JNI DLL depends on in the same folder as the JNI DLL (with the exception of any that will be installed in the GAC). You can then use its location to satisfy resolution requests. But remember to return `nullptr` if no file containing a manifest for an assembly with the requested name is present there. (This is likely the case with your ".resources" requests. If there isn't one it's okay unless you know otherwise.)

I'd be a little surprised if an assembly in a `Reference Assemblies` folder wasn't also in the GAC—but it'd be up to the assembly provider. [`Reference Assemblies`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msbuild/archive/2007/04/12/new-reference-assemblies-location.aspx) is for design and build tools (e.g. Visual Studio). (The old way was for each folder that had assemblies in it to be registered for each version of Visual Studio so the assemblies could be used for design and build.) If a dependency is not in the GAC, you can use the "Copy Local" property on the reference to make it available for debugging.

You might find the [Assembly Binding Log Viewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4.aspx) useful while designing and troubleshooting. With it you can see all the folders and extensions that are tried before giving over to calling the `AppDomain::AssemblyResolve` handler chain. (Disable logging when you are done.)

Comment: Thanks that already makes it a lot clearer to me. I already started to return a nullptr and now i finally know why.